# H1/H3 Tag Not Working On Mobile (iOS) via Squarespace

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-face, squarespace

Wondering if anyone had any advice. I'm a beginner coder, mainly can read it but not sure of all the language when writing it from scratch. Anyway, I'm working on a client's Squarespace website and using a custom uploaded font but for the life of me, I can't figure out why the `<h1>` and `<h3>` tags aren't working on mobile (not displaying the font), specifically on iPhone and iPad (so I assume iOS).

Site: orchid-flute-gfwg.squarespace.com

Here's what I'm working with:

```css
// Custom Font //
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Druk';
  src: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60e14b574a328e7c1d6e62b4/1625377623541/Druk+Wide+Super.ttf);
  src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60e22168d8478550d7974cc8/1625432424734/Druk+Wide+Super.eot");
  src: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60e2217cf28d5b6438dec0a6/1625432444301/Druk-WideSuper.woff") format("woff"),
  url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60d79feed113772d538dfa60/1624743919175/Druk+Wide+Super.otf") format("opentype"),
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Euclid';
  src: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60d7a016d2d2442e68e90958/1624743958321/EuclidCircularA-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oaklinn';
  src: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60d78e5b5e66bd5756e06a22/t/60d7a0fa2b37c143c11961f9/1624744186366/Oaklinn.otf);
}

// Custom Fonts Implement //
p {font-family: 'Euclid';}
h1 * {font-family: 'Druk' !important;}
h2 {font-family: 'Euclid';}
h3 {font-family: 'Druk' !important;}
h4 {font-family: 'Oaklinn';}
h5 {font-family: 'Euclid';}
button {font-family: 'Druk' !important; font-size: 10px !important;}
.sqs-block-button-element {
  font-family: 'Druk' !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;}
h3.portfolio-title {
    font-family: 'Druk' !important;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
.mobile-bar-wrapper *, h1 {
    font-family: 'Druk' !important;
}
h1.druk {
  font-family: 'Druk' !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){ 
    h3 { font-family: 'Druk' !important; }
    h1 { font-family: 'Druk' !important; }
}
```

I've tested some things out and noticed that the font works when used in a class, specifically in  but won't work in any of the Squarespace blocks or a custom code block via . I've even tried making a h1 class but that hasn't worked either. I've also added in all the file types for the font, but the 'Oaklinn' font is working fine on mobile even though it's only an otf.

I've even deleted all the coding and only left the font code on the website to see if there was any conflicting code, but it didn't help either.

Anyone have any clues as to why this is happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

So as a workaround because I need this usable by tomorrow, I've found this this is the only way the font will display on mobile... very weird and I don't understand why.

```css
.fix1 {
  background-color: none;
  color: #41474d;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Druk' !important;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) { .fix1 {
  background-color: none;
  color: #41474d;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Druk' !important;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  pointer-events: none;
  }}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [minimal reproduciable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for 
debugging details. Note that: `is not working` is not a very precise description. You have to be way more specific then that. How is it not working? What outcome is expected? What result do you get?

Comment: by not working, it doesn't not show up on mobile? I'm not sure how else to describe that the <h1> font doesn't show up on mobile.

Comment: Load woff2, woff, truetype and svg. This is cross-browser `@font-face { font-family: "Druk Wide Web Super"; src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/2f8845bdde42e943355a39765c5be5c0.woff2") format("woff2"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/2f8845bdde42e943355a39765c5be5c0.woff") format("woff"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/2f8845bdde42e943355a39765c5be5c0.ttf") format("truetype"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/2f8845bdde42e943355a39765c5be5c0.svg#Druk Wide Web Super") format("svg"); }`

Comment: @bron I pasted that in, but changed it to 'Druk' to allow all the other coding to match but it still didn't work, yet this class works in showing the correct font? I'm stumped. 

// PINK BUTTON //
.pinkbutton {
  background-color: #ff00a9;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  font-family: 'Druk' !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}